# create variable of either data type

Tags: java

I need to create a variable of either data type on runtime (via scanner class)

This is what my assignment asked

**"A selling arrangement could be an offered price OR an auction date"**

This is what i have created but not sure if it is correct..

```
public class SellingArrangement {

    private Object dateOrPrice;

    public SellingArrangement()
    {

    }
    public void setDateOrPrice(String price)
    {
        dateOrPrice = new Object();
        dateOrPrice = price;
    }
    public void setDateOrPrice(Double price)
    {
        dateOrPrice = new Object();
        dateOrPrice = price;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Why not have two separate member variables, one for date and one for price?

Comment: Your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels edited my question..

Comment: Yeah, your design is off, and you definitely don't want to do what you're trying above. jimpudar's ideas below seem cleanest to me.

Answer (score 3):

I have done something similar before (when an API may return JSON or XML)

However, you have two sets of two choices here - the input can either be a String or a Double, and that input can either represent a Date or a Price.

Instead of using an Object, I would just create two separate fields and populate the correct one using two separate constructors like this.

```
public class SellingArrangement {

    private Date date;
    private Price price;

    public SellingArrangement(String input)
    {
        if ( // String is a price ) {
            this.price = new Price(input);   
        }
        if ( // String is a date ) {
            this.date = new Date(input)
        }
    }
    public SellingArrangement(Double input)
    {
        if ( // Double is a price ) {
            this.price = new Price(input);   
        }
        if ( // Double is a date ) {
            this.date = new Date(input)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I am assuming you can figure out some way to validate whether the String or Double you are getting as input is a date or a price, and that you have constructors which will take a String / Double for each type. Treat this as pseudocode...

However as others have mentioned in comments if you dont **have** to do this with a single class, it would be better to use another method entirely...